# Sublists in order in haskell

Tags: haskell, sublist

All I wanna do is really simple but it seems hard for me to implement. I want a function in haskell with this behavior.

```
orderedsubs [2,5,3,4] = [[],[2],[2,5],[2,5,3],[2,5,3,4]]
```

Initially I thought about removing last element and put it to the list and repeat the process with the previously created list but once it's stored, it's gone. I don't care if the order of the sublists is different, but I want these specific sublists. So, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [inits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits) in Data.List:

> The `inits` function returns all initial segments of the argument,
>   shortest first. For example,
>
> ```
> inits "abc" == ["","a","ab","abc"]
> ```
>
> Note that `inits` has the following
>   strictness property: `inits _|_ = [] : _|_`

Comment: [Hoogle is your friend](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[a]%20-%3E%20[[a]])